# Singleton gets deallocated

Tags: objective-c, ios, ios5, cocos2d-iphone, ios6

I've created a simple singleton class to hold static data for my projects.
The first time I access this singleton is onEnter method in my Cocos2d scene. However when I try to access it again later in another method (same scene) this singleton is already released. I'm confused, how do I keep my singleton from being deallocated?

Here's my singleton's interface part:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface OrchestraData : NSObject
+(OrchestraData *)sharedOrchestraData;
@property (retain, readonly) NSArray *animalNames;
@end
```

Implementation:

```
#import "OrchestraData.h"

@implementation OrchestraData
@synthesize animalNames = animalNames_;

+(OrchestraData*)sharedOrchestraData
{
    static dispatch_once_t pred;
    static OrchestraData *_sharedOrchestraData = nil;

    dispatch_once(&pred, ^{ _sharedOrchestraData = [[OrchestraData alloc] init]; });
    return _sharedOrchestraData;
}

-(id)init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        animalNames_ = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"giraffe", @"giraffe", @"giraffe", @"giraffe", nil];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

I'm using my singleton this way:

```
[[OrchestraData sharedOrchestraData] animalNames];
```

Update:
I took a fresh look into it with NSZombies enabled, it appears as if my NSArrays were released, not the singleton itself. What do I do?

Comment: without code, how to help! :)

Comment: Seriously -- post some code.  How do you implement the singleton?  How do you access the singleton?

Comment: Sorry for not posting code earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RE Update:

Your `NSArray` deallocates because you're using the autorelease initializer `arrayWithObjects` and  you assign it directly to the ivar `animalNames_`. Therefore it is not retained.

To fix this, assign the array to the property:

```
self.animalNames = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"giraffe", @"giraffe", @"giraffe", @"giraffe", nil];
```

Btw, under ARC this wouldn't have been an issue since the ivar would have been a strong (retaining) reference. I don't get tired encouraging anyone to switch to ARC. It's been available for well over a year now and there's absolutely no point in using MRC code anymore! It really pains me to see how developers still don't use the easier, faster, and straightforward option. *(rant off)* :)

Comment: in this particular case the property is readonly. so it cant be used so easily. I would siggest to re-define the property as readwrite in a class extension.

Comment: Could you explain how using self.animalNames is different from assigning to animalNames_?

Comment: @devmiles.com — https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocProperties.html

Comment: Didn't find the answer there. I know self.animalNames just calls setter method which doesn't exist for readonly properties. But how would I initialize readonly property correctly without autorelease behaviour?

Comment: You're correct using self.animalNames calls the getter and setter which retains your underlying instance variable defined in your synthesise. Going straight to to using the ivar (instance variable) is fine but the first time you use you need to declare it to be retained.

Answer (score 4):

You must implement your singleton in this way:

1) in .h file of your Singleton Class:

```
+ (SingletonClass *)instance;
```

2) in .m file:

```
+ (SingletonClass *)instance {

    static SingletonClass* instance = nil;
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        instance = [[self alloc] init];
        //your init code here
    });
    return instance;
}
```

If you want to call your singleton, just call `[SingletonClass instance]`.

If your are interesting what is "dispatch_once_t", read about Grand Central Dispatch:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html

Comment: vai-vai-kitay has the right answer.  The singleton should be maintaining a pointer to itself (in this case, `instance`) to avoid deallocation.

Comment: Right;   I would suggest naming the method `sharedInstance` and having it return either `id` or `instancetype`.

Comment: Would be nice if you could tell how this implementation is different from devmiles' code, because I don't see it. Technically both code samples are identical, unless I overlooked something (I double checked though). Btw, following Cocoa naming conventions it should be called sharedOrchestraData.

Answer (score -2):

You setup a pointer wherever you need it.

```
-(void)someMethod {

MySingleton *singleton = [MySingleton sharedSingleton];
singleton.data = YES; //dumb example to show you did something...

}

-(void)someOtherMethod {

MySingleton *singleton = [MySingleton sharedSingleton]; //You have to create a new pointer...
singleton.data = NO; //another dumber example to show you did something...

}
```

Note: this assumes that you have created a singleton the same way I have... your code might be different therefore causing my answer not to apply...

Comment: Not all singletons are alike, though. Note that `Class` objects are already singletons, so if you want to make everything a Class method you can.

Comment: Not to mention that ARC isn't going to release something assigned to a `static` variable, which a properly written singleton should be.

Answer (score -3):

You need to overwrite the below method inside your singleton class, because in your program, if someone has initialised `[[SingletonClass alloc] init]` then singleton will have another instance and release it will cause an error.

```
+ (id)allocWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    return [[self SingletonClass] retain];  
}

- (id)copyWithZone:(NSZone *)zone{
    return self;
}

- (id)retain{
    return self;
}
```

Comment: You don't need to override any of those.